# ASP.NET MVC2 Routing Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have two controllers with the same name in different sub folder
My Controllers looks like

- Controllers

  - api

    - UserController
  - help

    - UserController

I want to access my first controller when the user requests `http://mysite/api/User/Index`

and access my second controller when the user requests `http://mysite/help/User/Index`

how to configure routing in Global.asax and how the views folders will look like?

will it look like?

- Views

  - User

    - api

      - Index
    - help

      - Index

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use namespace constraints:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "help",
    "help/{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "User", action = "Index" },
    new[] { "MvcApplication1.Controllers.help" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "api",
    "api/{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "User", action = "Index" },
    new[] { "MvcApplication1.Controllers.api" }
);
```

As far as having sub-folders for your Views is concerned, this is not supported out of the box. You will have to write a [custom view engine](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx) for this to work.

By the way have you considered using [Areas](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/aspnet-mvc-2-areas)? They seem like better fit for your scenario. So you would define 2 areas: `help` and `api` and have the UserController defined in both.